# Compiler: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_81.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm getting error LNK1104 from build for file `libboost_serialization-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_81.lib`  when trying to build my .cpp file. Here are my include directories:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include "boost\asio.hpp"
#include "boost\serialization\serialization.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp"
#include <utility>
```

My visual studio toolset is:
[image: 1]

Which absolutely matches with the libboost library. I am building in Debug mode on x64. My additional include directories for both VC++ and under C/C++ > General are:

[image]

And `C:\local\boost_1_81_0\stage\lib` absolutely has a file by the name of `libboost_serialization-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_81.lib` in it:

[image]

I compiled the boost library by running `bootstrap.bat` and then `b2.exe`. I cannot fathom why this file can't be opened... It exists, and boost is compiled. Any help?

Comment: The additional include directories are used for inclusion in your source code, it has nothing to do with linking to libraries.

Comment: I see. Where in Visual Studio do I indicate that stage/lib contains necessary files? @tkausl

Comment: It's obviously in the linker section.

Comment: @273K I'd appreciate you leaving a useful comment instead of an unhelpful and emotional one. Yes, you are right, it is obviously in the Linker section, but the stating the specific setting would've made your comment have value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also provide the `stage\lib` path for the Linker under Linker > All Options > Additional Library Directories.